# How do I print a MKMapView in OS X?

Tags: cocoa, printing, mkmapview, mapkit, nsprintoperation

Sending a `MKMapView` a `-print:` message results in an output that only contains the +/- buttons and the "legal" link. Same if I try `[NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:someMKMapView]` or `[theWindowThatContainsAMapView print]` or `[[NSPrintOperation PDFOperationWithView:someMKMapView insideRect:someMKMapView.bounds toPath:@"foo.pdf" printInfo:nil] runOperation]`.

Apple's own Maps.app does print the map, btw.

Has anyone managed to print a MKMapView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The magic class is `MKMapSnapshotter`

Assuming there is a `MKMapView` instance `mapView`, this is a simple example to create an image of the current content of MKMapView as TIFF file written in Swift.
This image is printable.

```
let options = MKMapSnapshotOptions()
options.region = mapView.region;
options.size = mapView.frame.size;

let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:"/path/to/snapshot.tif")
let mapSnapshotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: options)
mapSnapshotter.startWithCompletionHandler { (snapshot, error) -> Void in
  // do error handling
  let image = snapshot.image
  if let data = image.TIFFRepresentation {
    data.writeToURL(fileURL!, atomically:true)
  } else {
    println("could not create TIFF data")
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

with printing instead of creating a file

```
let options = MKMapSnapshotOptions()
options.region = mapView.region;
options.size = mapView.frame.size;

let mapSnapshotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: options)
mapSnapshotter.startWithCompletionHandler { (snapshot, error) -> Void in
  // do error handling
  let image = snapshot.image
  let imageView = NSImageView()
  imageView.frame = NSRect(origin: NSZeroPoint, size: image.size)
  imageView.image = image

  let info = NSPrintInfo.sharedPrintInfo()
  info.horizontalPagination = .FitPagination
  info.verticalPagination = .FitPagination
  let operation = NSPrintOperation(view: imageView, printInfo:info)
  operation.showsPrintPanel = true
  operation.runOperation()
```

Comment: Worth noting, from the documentation: "Snapshot images do not include any custom overlays or annotations that your app added to the map view. If you want your annotations and overlays to appear on the final image, you must draw them yourself. To position those items correctly on the image, use the pointForCoordinate: method of this class to translate the overlay or annotation coordinate value to an appropriate location inside the image’s coordinate space."

Comment: please read this : http://nshipster.com/mktileoverlay-mkmapsnapshotter-mkdirections/