# How to print a SwiftUI View

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit

I want to use **SwiftUI** View to print something like labels on macOS (Ventura). But that results in a blank paper:

```swift
func startPrinting() {
    let printView = NSHostingView(rootView: Text("I want to print"))
    printView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)

    let printInfo = NSPrintInfo()
    printInfo.topMargin = 0
    printInfo.leftMargin = 0
    printInfo.bottomMargin = 0
    printInfo.rightMargin = 0

    let printOperation = NSPrintOperation(view: printView, printInfo: printInfo)
    printOperation.run()
}
```

When I switch `Text` to `TextField`, it is printed, but I don't know why.

How can I print a **SwiftUI** View?

Comment: Same with me. It worked with macOS 12 before. Seems to be bug in Ventura.

Comment: @FPP Per the release notes, it looks like this was fixed on macOS 13.5 and macOS 14. Are you still running into this issue?

Comment: @Jake3231: Yes, you're right. The problem is gone for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to print a SwiftUI view. In my case an annotated map view. There don't seem to be many suggestions on the web. I added function provided to attempt to print a ContentView using Xcode 14 and Xcode 15 with similar results but no full solution.

```
import SwiftUI

func startPrinting() {
    let printView = NSHostingView(rootView: ContentView())
    printView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)

    let printInfo = NSPrintInfo()
    printInfo.topMargin = 0
    printInfo.leftMargin = 0
    printInfo.bottomMargin = 0
    printInfo.rightMargin = 0

    let printOperation = NSPrintOperation(view: printView, printInfo: printInfo)
    printOperation.run()
}
```

// From: [How to print a SwiftUI View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74440592/how-to-print-a-swiftui-view)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var someText = "Text here"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text(someText)
            TextField("A textfield", text: $someText)
            Button("Print this View") {
                startPrinting()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Changing the rootView allowed printing some elements in ContentView. Not the globe. Not text entered in the textfield. It did include the Text contents, the TextField prompt and the button text in the Print preview pane that appeared.

Comment: You can capture and print map views with `MKMapSnapshotter`

Comment: Hi vadian, thanks for the suggestion but I haven't been able to get MKMapSnapshotter to work. That is I haven't found any useful code to print the one mapview I've been able to generate. Can you point me to a tutorial or some simple code to print the mapView with MKMapSnapshotter. Thanks

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558362/how-do-i-print-a-mkmapview-in-os-x/31185995#31185995

Comment: Are you still seeing this on macOS 14?

Comment: Still no markers or other annotation

Answer (score 0):

@vadian I was able to add a button to print the mapView but no annotations so far.

```
            Button("Print Map") {
                let options = MKMapSnapshotter.Options()
                options.region = centerRegion // defined above
                options.size = CGSize(width: 600, height: 800)
                
                let mapSnapshotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: options)
                mapSnapshotter.start { (snapshot, error) -> Void in
                    
                let imageView = NSImageView()
                imageView.frame = NSRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 600, height: 800))
                imageView.image = image
                
                let info = NSPrintInfo.shared
                info.horizontalPagination = .fit
                info.verticalPagination = .fit
                let operation = NSPrintOperation(view: imageView, printInfo: info)
                
                operation.showsPrintPanel = true
                operation.run()
            }
        }
    }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
    
// Under Signing and Capabilities > App Sandbox > Hardware > Printing checked
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757185/swift-3-add-custom-annotation-pin-to-mkmapsnapshotter-snapshot) helps